# Where should I put the code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the models User and StoredItem:

```
class UserData < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stored_items, :dependent => :destroy
end

class StoredItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  named_scope :lookup, lambda { |id| { :conditions => ['qid = ?', id]}}
end
```

I need to have two methods to add and remove the items to StoredItem for current user.  I put this code to User model:

```
class UserData < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stored_items, :dependent => :destroy

  def save_item(params)
    if(!self.stored_items.lookup(params[:qid]).exists?)
      item = self.stored_items.new(:sid => params[:qid],
                                   :name => params[:qti],
                                   :url => params[:qur],
                                   :group_id => params[:title],
                                   :rating => Integer(params[:rating]))
      item.save
    end
  end

  def remove_item(qid)
    item = self.stored_items.lookup(qid).first()
    item.destroy
  end
end
```

So here is the StoredItem controller:

```
def save_item
  @user = UserData.find_by_login(session[:cuser])
  @user.save_item(params)
  # ...
end
```

Is it good architectural decision or it will be better to put this code to StoredItem model and pass the current user into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good architectural decision. You need to keep it in the user since the User is the owner of the StoredItem. The user is responsible for its stored items, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, but my user is responsible for many entities(items, locations, contacts....) and it tends to a very big User model. I am not sure it is good.

Comment: User models are naturally responsible for a lot in applications. If you want, you can create modules (place them in your lib directory) and include them in your user class. This way you can separate the functionality. Let me know if you want to answer the question again with the module concept or if you know what I'm getting at.